# I have problem with detecting the width of the screen in React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I create Hook to detect the width & the height of Screen:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const getWindowDimensions = () => {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return { width, height }
};
export function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(
    getWindowDimensions()
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```

and inside the component I called the `useWindowDimensions`  hook and I console.log the width:

```
 const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
 console.log(width, "width");
```

and in the Console the width wasn't accurate at all:
[image]

Note:  when I refresh the page it detects the width perfectly

any clue how can I fix this ?

Comment: Where exactly is your `console.log()`? If it is only logging during the render and a render happens while you are mid-resize, it may show the wrong width (Though I can't see any reason this would actually be a problem as it should update immediately, it would just be a misleading console output)

Comment: I set up [a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-field-5k3bi?file=/src/App.js) using your code and it works like a charm. Maybe you have a problem in other parts of your app? For example. in a component where you use `useWindowDimensions`.

Comment: @DBS yeah, but how can I fix this and make it make detect the current width

Comment: @fromaline  can you explain, what could be wrong ?

Comment: Can you setup a reproducing example of the problem? The code in your question seems to work correctly (As seen in fromaline's CodeSandbox)

Comment: @MohamedAhmed, yeah I can, but I need [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) fot it. Can you provide it, please?